# Imported Maven Project into Eclipse 3.7 (m2e 1.0) but src/main/java are not shown as source-package

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I have a maven (3.0.4) multi-module build project which works on command line perfect.

```
mvn clean package
```

build successful.

I've tried to import that project into Eclipse

[image]

with m2e 1.0.

[image]

but after it's ready i can't see a package folder nor the icon for src-folders (like src/main/java etc).

[image]

But i would have expected to see something like the following:

[image]

Does someone has a hint what problem might be? Or ideas where to look for?

**Update**

After boiling this down it might be caused by using a Java 1.7. compiler which i have configurate like the following:

```
 <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
            <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            <executable>C:/Programme/Java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/javac</executable>
            <fork>true</fork>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
```

Someone with experience in this area?

Comment: As I see, for some reason it doesn't set Java nature for the project (missing J letter in its icon). Did you try `Update Project Configuration`? If didn't help, paste your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Updated several times. Removed also .project, .classpath, .settings folder before and imported it an other time. But no luck.

Comment: OK, so paste your POM. What I would look at is `<packaging>` and `<build>` sections.

Comment: packaging in the root is pom and the other packages have jar (default).

Comment: Which import wizard did you use?

Comment: Observing the identical behaviour. The suggestions in this issue so far didn't help me out. As at import time (Import existing Maven project) there is no .classpath and .project those can't be the solutions. And I dind't find a "wrong lifecycle mapping". Any other ideas? thx all!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your project doesn't have a Java nature.  You can change this by right-clicking the project and going to

Properties -> Project Facets -> Convert to faceted form

From there you can add a Java facet, which should do the job.  I often find with this sort of thing that it's easier to just edit Eclipse's `.project` and `.classpath` files manually (make sure to back them up before you do though!) instead.  You'll probably want to check that your project's `.project` file includes something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    ...
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Then make sure your `.classpath` looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    ...
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Once you've got all this stuff ready to go, update your project configuration like Michal said and refresh.

Comment: .project and .classpath are auto-generated with correct nature when you import existing maven projects. I don't see any point why it is generated incorrectly if using correct way import the maven project.

Comment: That's not always the case in my experience, especially when languages other than Java are involved.  Plus if you want to add these natures later on, for example if you have a Maven project and subsequently add Java code to it, I find the UI doesn't always do a great job.  Anyway, it's still worth checking these files to ensure they have the correct entries, as they're the ones that Eclipse will be looking at.

Answer (score 3):

After long fiddling around i've found the problem which solves it for me:

I had a wrong lifecycle mapping for the maven-compiler-plugin (2.5.1) in my configuration which caused the problems. After removing it it works as expected no need to change the facets manually just import the project and it works.

Comment: Could please be a little more specific about what was wrong? I am having the identical problem, but I didn't find any custom lifecycle mapping for this plugin in my project. Also your `pom.xml` snippet doesn't show any!? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your eclipse, it might be pointing to `JRE` instead of `JDK`.
Go to `window->preference->java->Installed JRE`. Add JDK here, and set it to default.
You may need to restart eclipse.